# Can I determine the type of an rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a serialize function that performs differently based on the type. I'd like to be able to call it with both `f(x)` and `f(5)`, but `f(5)` fails with error `No matching function for call to 'f', Candidate function [with T = int] not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument.` If I change `f(T& t)` to `f(T&& t)` then `f(x)` is not arithmetic. How can I recognize both `f(x)` and `f(5)` to be arithmetic, and similarly for any type such as the string type below? I don't want to force the input to be const because I want to alter it otherwise.

```
template<typename T>
void f(T& t)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic_v<T>)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
    {
        // do other stuff
    }
    else
    {
        //alter non-const input
    }
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    f(x);
    f(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not take the argument by `const&` instead?

Comment: @cigien. Sorry I forgot to mention that I don't want to make it const. I edited the question.

Comment: Ok, could you explain what it means to alter `5`? If you just mean to alter a copy, then take the argument by copy, i.e. `T t`.

Comment: @cigien. I don't want to alter 5. I want 5 to fall in the is_arithmetic block.

Comment: Your code is already doing that part right. I should have asked for this already, but please paste the error message as well.

Comment: @cigien. if f is defined as f(T& t), then I get the error "No matching function for call to 'f'", "Candidate function [with T = int] not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument"

Comment: Add that to the question please, not a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a forwarding reference, `T&&`, to take the argument by either lvalue- or rvalue reference depending on what's passed in.

In case of lvalue, `T = int&`, so we need to use `std::decay_t` to remove the reference from the type.

When we pass an rvalue, `T = int` and decay does nothing.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void f(T&& t)
{
    using T_Type = std::decay_t<T>; // remove const/reference from the type
    if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic_v<T_Type>)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T_Type, std::string>)
    {
        // do other stuff
    }
    else
    {
        //alter non-const input
    }
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    f(x);
    f(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `std::decay` performs

> Applies lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, and function-to-pointer implicit conversions to the type T

If any of those cases is not desired, you can use a combination of `std::remove_reference` and `std::remove_const`, or in case of c++20 we can use `std::remove_cvref`.